# Sort realm results using a property of an element in a list

Tags: swift, sorting, realm

I have two realm classes... the first class `Patient` contains one or more of a second class `Record`, as the following:

```
class Patient: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var records: List<Record>

}

class Record: EmbeddedObject {
    @Persisted var date = Date()

    @Persisted(originProperty: "records") var patient: LinkingObjects<Patient>

}
```

I want to sort `patients` by the `date` of the last `record`, something like this:

```
patients = realm.objects(Patient.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "records.last.date", ascending: false)
```

Is this possible with realm and swift?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective is to sort patients by the latest date of a record in their in their list of records.

It can be done and there are several approaches. One option is, as patients records are being populated, to keep a separate property of the record with the latest date.

The patient object would look something like this

```
class Patient: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted private var records: List<Record>
    @Persisted var lastRecord: Record!

    func addRecord(withRecod: Record) {
        self.records.append(withRecord)
        let recordArray = Array(self.records)

        if withRecod != nil {
            let sortedRecords = recordArray.sorted { $0.date < $1.date }
            let lastRecord = sortedRecords.last!
            let rec = Record(value: lastRecord)
            self.lastRecord = rec
        }
    }
}
```

We added a function to populate the records list and made that list private so you are forced to use the `addRecord` function to populate the property.

The Array is needed as Realm doesn't sort in memory - so if the object is not yet persisted the records cannot be sorted, so an array is leveraged for that task.

Lastly, the array is sorted by date and then we make a COPY of the last record to store in the lastRecord property. Embedded objects are never persisted 'on their own' they can't be referenced in the same way other objects can, so a copy makes it work.

Then the sorting becomes easy

```
let patients = realm.objects(Patient.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "lastRecord.date")
```

Keeping in mind a `updateRecord` and a `deleteRecord` function may be in order to re-calculate the `lastRecord` upon those changes.

Comment: Rather than adding a Record property to Patient why not add a Date property instead that stores the date of the last patient record?

Comment: @RobC A few reasons - if it's strictly a date (ignoring the time stamp aspect), you could have several records with the same date. Also, if you want to get additional data about that record there would be additional code to read the date, and then and additional query for the embedded objects for the matching Record. Whereas if it's at the top level, no query would be needed. It's certainly not a bad suggestion by any means but it depends on the use case.